# R separate multiple columns into list

Tags: r, list, function, for-loop, dataframe

I tried to write a function to separate the columns into each data frame with keeping first four columns and each sample in a data frame. Below is the sample:

```
df:
Name    RsID    Chr Position    Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 Sample4 Sample5 Sample6 Sample7
200610-1    rs423874    MT  2755    AA  AA  AA  AA  AA  AA  AA
200610-10   rs94753345  MT  0   AA  AA  AA  AA  AA  AA  AA
200610-100  rs36757 MT  15172   GG  GG  GG  GG  GG  GG  GG
200610-102  rs1444029   MT  125 AA  AA  AA  AA  AA  AA  AA
200610-105  rs3796687   MT  236 AA  AA  TT  AA  AA  AT  AA
200610-107  rs483795    MT  482 TT  AA  AA  TT  AA  AA  AA

desired output:
Name    RsID    Chr Position    Sample1
200610-1    rs423874    MT  2755    AA
200610-10   rs94753345  MT  0   AA
200610-100  rs36757 MT  15172   GG
200610-102  rs1444029   MT  125 AA
200610-105  rs3796687   MT  236 AA
200610-107  rs483795    MT  482 TT

Name    RsID    Chr Position    Sample2
200610-1    rs423874    MT  2755    AA
200610-10   rs94753345  MT  0   AA
200610-100  rs36757 MT  15172   GG
200610-102  rs1444029   MT  125 AA
200610-105  rs3796687   MT  236 AA
200610-107  rs483795    MT  482 AA   

...

code:
sep_col <- function(df,i) {if (length(i) <= 1) { x <- cbind(df[1:4],df[i])} 
else { x <- list()
for(s in 1:length(i)) {y <- cbind(df[1:4],df[i[s]])
  x[[s]] <- list(y)}}
return(x)}
```

It works if I write df[1:4] inside the function, however if i change back to df only in the function and run, there is an error:

```
sep_col(df[1:4],6)

Error:
Error in `[.data.frame`(df, i) : undefined columns selected
Called from: `[.data.frame`(df, i)
```

I don't know why it is incorrect, but both class are 'data.frame', so anyone can advice, thank you.

Comment: perhaps `lapply(df[,-(1:4)], function(values) cbind(df[,1:4],values))` ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Map` to bind the columns 1:4 separately with each of the columns 5 to 11 and assign the `names` of the corresponding columns with `setNames`

```
Map(function(x, y, z) cbind(x, setNames(list(y), z)), 
                   list(df[1:4]), df[5:11], names(df)[5:11])
#[[1]]
#        Name       RsID Chr Position Sample1
#1   200610-1   rs423874  MT     2755      AA
#2  200610-10 rs94753345  MT        0      AA
#3 200610-100    rs36757  MT    15172      GG
#4 200610-102  rs1444029  MT      125      AA
#5 200610-105  rs3796687  MT      236      AA

#[[2]]
#        Name       RsID Chr Position Sample2
#1   200610-1   rs423874  MT     2755      AA
#2  200610-10 rs94753345  MT        0      AA
#3 200610-100    rs36757  MT    15172      GG
#4 200610-102  rs1444029  MT      125      AA
#5 200610-105  rs3796687  MT      236      AA

#[[3]]
#        Name       RsID Chr Position Sample3
#1   200610-1   rs423874  MT     2755      AA
#2  200610-10 rs94753345  MT        0      AA
#3 200610-100    rs36757  MT    15172      GG
#4 200610-102  rs1444029  MT      125      AA
#5 200610-105  rs3796687  MT      236      TT

#[[4]]
#        Name       RsID Chr Position Sample4
#1   200610-1   rs423874  MT     2755      AA
#2  200610-10 rs94753345  MT        0      AA
#3 200610-100    rs36757  MT    15172      GG
#4 200610-102  rs1444029  MT      125      AA
#5 200610-105  rs3796687  MT      236      AA

#[[5]]
#        Name       RsID Chr Position Sample5
#1   200610-1   rs423874  MT     2755      AA
#2  200610-10 rs94753345  MT        0      AA
#3 200610-100    rs36757  MT    15172      GG
#4 200610-102  rs1444029  MT      125      AA
#5 200610-105  rs3796687  MT      236      AA

#[[6]]
#        Name       RsID Chr Position Sample6
#1   200610-1   rs423874  MT     2755      AA
#2  200610-10 rs94753345  MT        0      AA
#3 200610-100    rs36757  MT    15172      GG
#4 200610-102  rs1444029  MT      125      AA
#5 200610-105  rs3796687  MT      236      AT

#[[7]]
#        Name       RsID Chr Position Sample7
#1   200610-1   rs423874  MT     2755      AA
#2  200610-10 rs94753345  MT        0      AA
#3 200610-100    rs36757  MT    15172      GG
#4 200610-102  rs1444029  MT      125      AA
#5 200610-105  rs3796687  MT      236      AA
```

---

Or with `lapply`, loop through the column names 5 to 11, subset the dataset with that column and `cbind` with the first 4 columns of dataset

```
lapply(names(df)[5:11], function(x) cbind(df[1:4], df[x]))
```